# How to make Dictionary<double, double> from List<double>

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I am learning LINQ I ran into a problem like in topic. I dont know how to convert List into Dictionary<double, double>, where Key is double from list, and Value is square of this number. I know about method like .ToDictionary() but dont know how to use it in my case.

input: List num = new List{2,3,4,5}

output: 2->4, 3->9, etc...

Comment: how would you do it using a loop? If you know that, you can easily transform that to a linq-expression.

Comment: Having said this, what did you try?

Answer (score 0):

```cs
var squared = numbers.ToDictionary(x => x, x => x * x);
```

However, IMO this is very unnecessary. Performing the multiplication is probably cheaper than a dictionary lookup.

Comment: Maybe this is silly example and real world requires getting values in both keyFunc and valueFunc

Answer (score 0):

May be better to do the multiplication when required instead.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var dataSet = new List<double>()
        {
            2,3,4,5
        };
        
        var result = dataSet.ToDictionary(k => k, v => v * v);
        foreach(var kv in result)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}",kv.Key, kv.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
2 = 4
3 = 9
4 = 16
5 = 25
```